# Cake not calling beforeSave on a HABTM relationship

Tags: php, cakephp, model, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship set up between my `Post` model and `Tag` model.

I want a `beforeSave()` method in my `Tag` model which will execute when tags are saved.

Problem is, in my controller I'm calling `$this->Post->save($this->request->data);` and it doesn't seem to fire the `beforeSave()` method in the `Tag` model, even though they have a relationship between them and tags *do* get saved along with the post.

I could put my logic in the `beforeSave()` method of the `Post` model, but then I'd have tag related logic in my `Post` model which doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to fire the `beforeSave()` method in my `Tag` model when a post gets saved?

Comment: Are you use saveAll to save your post? put your beforeSave code in your post.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using saveAll?

```
$this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Comment: this is not answer, you must put it in comment.

Comment: It should be the answer, allowing for the fact their may be an issue elsewhere. Not sure why you have duplicated this suggestion in your own badly written comment...